# Open Console Application inside Unified Service Desk

Tags: console, dynamics-crm, console-application, unified-service-desk

I have a requirement where i need to open a Console Application inside Unified Service Desk v4.1.

The issue with me is I am able to open the console application inside Unified Service Desk, However I am unable to write anything inside it. The console application is just appearing as an image inside USD.

So, how can I open the console application inside Unified Service Desk and make the Console application work?

Comment: can you show us an image?what happens?

Answer (score 0):

Console application is actually hosted using CCA application. The issue with these applications are once opened, then they become unresponsive. 
1. Create a UII Windows Forms Adapter
2. Trigger the process and execute your console application
3. Using Win32.dll setParent Command, pull the application inside your Adapter and that would be it.

Hope this will help